# Minimum number of additions required for all elements to be divisible by the same integer

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math

I got this question on an interview recently.

Given an array of integers, what is the minimum sum of integers to be added so that the resulting array is divisible by some integer?

**For example**

Given an input array [4, 7, 5, 11, 15]:

If you want to make the array divisible by 2, you would add [0, 1, 1, 1, 1] to each element in the array to get a resulting array of [4, 8, 6, 12, 16]. The sum of the adding array is 4.

If you want to make the array divisible by 3, you would add [2, 2, 1, 1, 0] to each element in the array to get a resulting array of [6, 9, 6, 12, 15]. The sum of the adding array is 6.

This can go on to make the array divisible by 4, 5, and so on. In this example, the correct answer is 4 (making the array divisible by 2).

**Proposed solution**

The maximum answer is n where n is the length of the array since you can just make the array divisible by 2. My solution is to iterate over all primes from 2 to the max of the input array, find the sum of added numbers, and take the minimum of those sums.

Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Do you know the maximun values of n and of the numbers?

Comment: The answer is always 0 since all integers are already divisible by 1.

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your proposed solution. Why should I iterate primes from 2? What about 1 that is used in both examples? What do you understand by a maximum answer, don't you ask about the minimum sum of integers?

Comment: Maximum value of n and the numbers can be assumed to be INT_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do this is to iterate over the array `arr` and perform a modulo operation of the given integer `d` on each of its elements. The sum of reminders is the answer.

```java
   int findMinSum(int[] arr, int d) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var e : arr){
            var mod = e % d;
            sum += mod;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

Comment: But `d` isn't given; we are asked to find the minimum possible value of `sum` over all possible values of `d`.